# Redefine mathematical symbols in size

Tags: symbols, size

I just figured out, that the greater equal symbol, \geq, don't look as I want it to look when I print my document. Because I used it very often, I want to redefine the \geq command resulting in another version.

Firstly it is to big. I found the package scalerel and managed to scale it and redefine it:

```
\let\oldgeq\geq
\renewcommand{\geq}{\scaleobj{0.8}{\oldgeq}}
```

That works fine, the spaces are too small, but that's not the point here.

Secondly, the bottom line of the symbol is not aligned with the rest of the text. It' a bit below the rest if you look closely. So I tried to align it or set it a little over the textline, but it didn't work. I found a work-around with tikz, but then it only fits in the right place in normalfont. I want it to align with the text in every fontsize, so this isn't a good solution.

Maybe someone can help me with my second problem or have an even better solution for the whole problem?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\let\oldgeq\geq
\renewcommand{\geq}{\scaleobj{0.8}{\oldgeq}}

\begin{document}
$5\oldgeq8$ $5\geq8$
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To fix the spacing, `\renewcommand{\geq}{\mathrel{\scaleobj{0.8}{\oldgeq}}}`.  That is, make the renew'ed macro of class `\mathrel` (math relation).

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure what you dislike about the standard symbol. Anyway, you can and should use `\mathpalette`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\let\oldgeq\geq
\let\oldleq\leq
\renewcommand{\geq}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\bueckirel\oldgeq}}
\renewcommand{\leq}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\bueckirel\oldleq}}
\newcommand{\bueckirel}[2]{%
  \raisebox{\depth}{\scalebox{0.8}{$#1#2$}}%
}

\begin{document}

$5\oldgeq8$ $5\geq8_{a\geq b}$

$5\oldleq8$ $5\leq8_{a\leq b}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify, I am perfectly fine with the standard symbol, but the supervisor of my project was very unhappy with it, so I just had to find a solution. However, it seems to work, thanks. So just to learn something new: the \mathpalette is there to choose the font size?

Comment: @buecki Look for it on the site, you'll find several examples

Comment: sorry, but the position in the subscript looks just terrible.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Tell it to the OP's supervisor

Answer (score 3):

This sets the base of the revised `\geq` to the same depth as the original, and also fixes the horizontal spacing.  EDITED to handle smaller math styles.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine}

\let\oldgeq\geq
\newcommand{\geqaux}{\mathrel{\scaleobj{0.8}{\oldgeq}}}
\renewcommand\geq{\mathrel{\ThisStyle{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle\geqaux$}
  \edef\dpgeq{\the\dp0}
  \abovebaseline[-\dpgeq]{$\SavedStyle\geqaux$}
}}}
%\renewcommand\geq{\mathrel{\ThisStyle{\abovebaseline[0pt]{$\SavedStyle\geqaux$}}}}

\begin{document}
$5\oldgeq8\quad 5\geq8$

$\scriptstyle 5\oldgeq8\quad 5\geq8$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one actually wanted the horizontal slash of the symbol to be on the number baseline itself, then use the commented version of the `\geq` redefinition, resulting in

[image]

Comment: Thank a lot, this works very well. I just check it with the different font style I use in my project.

Comment: the traditional design of relational and binary operators has them vertically centered on the math axis (the vertical position of a minus sign, the cross of a plus, or the position of a fraction line).  by moving one such symbol off this axis, there is a danger that it will look out of position in relation to others that are close by.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I understand.  However, i was just responding to the OP's complaint that "the bottom line of the symbol is not aligned with the rest of the text"

Comment: good enough for grade school math.  *not* good enough for postgraduate level.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Ouch!  That left a mark.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I would only add that while, technically, the center of the original `\geq` may align with the math axis, there is nothing about the appearance that looks symmetric.  For example,  the tip of `>` aligns with `-`, but not the tip of the original `\geq`. I personally find it quite ugly in that regard.

Comment: in a more complicated context, if both `\geq` and `\leq` appear, and are aligned so that the "points" of the ">" and '<" are on the math axis, the result looks like it is trying to represent something different from inequality.  (i do think i've seen that notation used somewhere for such a purpose, with the notation defined specifically for the document by the author.  i find it quite confusing.)

Comment: well, I personally don't like it. But as I mentioned before, I'm working on a bigger project and my supervisor told me that he want the \geq and \leq bottom line aligned with the rest. So your solutions solve my problem of following the orders of him. But in fact I see the problems with other mathematical symbols and the thing as a whole. Maybe I should try to talk to him about this again. However, thanks!

Comment: What if we want to redefine "="? Can it be done? I don't understand catcode magic, so I can't tell if it is possible.